# What is BigData and why it is a need now a days?

Tags: bigdata

Now a days, there is only one buzz that goes on...Big Data..Curious to know what it is ..Though I have gleaned some information from [Big Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) but want to know more.

Thanks

Comment: There are easily a thousand other buzz topics other than big data.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for SO. Maybe programmers.SE?

Comment: have you tried googling, there are lots of good blogs out there..

Answer (score 8):

The difference between a database for a coffee shop, and for facebook. It's easy to get something to work with 200 users. But when you have 200,000 users... that's a different story.

Table scans become impossible. Indexes become very important.

Single servers cannot handle all the load. Solutions such as clustering are employed to make it so more than one server can host an application. This makes it so you can keep adding more servers to the cluster each time the load gets too big and performance starts to die.

You'll hear a lot about NoSQL databases too such as MongoDB. This is where the database just stores key/value documents. Such databases are more suited for massive scaling (by sharding) than are relational database systems.

Comment: I up-voted you because you succinctly nailed the 'need for bigdata' - 'between a db at a coffee shop and ...', your supporting reasons, true and not true. :p